# display list of possibilities by entering value in combobox/choice Java

Tags: java, listview, combobox

I have a editable combobox which contains data from a mysql table.
What I want to do is when entering a value in the combobox it should show me the possibilities.

f.e.:

```
column1 
E120
E110
O100
```

So when I am entering "E" in the combobox there should be displayed a list of the two values.

```
E120
E110
```

And also it should be not possible to enter "E121".

Which methode I can use to do this?
thanks

Comment: Please consider upvoting answers which were helpful, and also accepting an answer if it is what you were looking for.  These are ways which we help promote useful content on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use GlazedLists**

I don't have sample code, because we used this at my last job and I don't have access to the software repository.  I do remember that it was extremely easy to get this up and running.  Check out the [javadoc for GlazedLists' AutoCompleteSupport](https://svn.java.net/svn/glazedlists~svn/tags/glazedlists-1_9_0/www/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/swing/AutoCompleteSupport.html) class for more details.

It's very nice that you don't have to implement a whole framework or change your combo box.  I recall this having a one-line solution to add auto-complete support.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go, which is pretty useful for this, is by using [Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Check [this](http://rmandvikar.blogspot.ca/2008/10/trie-examples.html) out.